# How to make a Razor template for a frequently used Kendo control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Razor MVC webpage that makes heavy use of Kendo charts/grids.

Some of these grids and charts are found in multiple locations and it's important that the look and feel is identical

right now I've been reusing my backend code quite well by copying the .cshtml between views

with this technique, I do get good backend code reuse, but it'd be awesome to reuse the chart,  is this possible?

can I somehow put this code into it's own .cshtml file and then reference it from multiple locations?  maybe a Razor version of #include? :S

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Chart<AuthTest.Models.HardDriveUsagePieSlice>().Theme("Uniform")
                  .Name("chart" + s.Key.ToString()).Title(title => title.Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
                  .Legend(legend => legend
                      .Visible(false)
                  )
                  .Series(series =>
                  {
                      series.Pie(model => model.Percent, model => model.Title)

                          .Labels(labels => labels
                              .Template("#= category #: #= value#%")
                              .Background("transparent")
                              .Visible(true)
                          ).StartAngle(150);
                  })
                  .DataSource(x => x.Read(r => r.Action("_Usage", "Home", new {ID=s.Value.Id, UID=Model.UID})))
                  .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                        .Visible(true)
                        .Format("{0}%")
                  ).Transitions(false)
                  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done was create an html helper that returns a kendo grid.  Your helper is just a regular extension that can be written like so:

```
public static class KendoChartHelper
{
    public static Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ChartBuilder<T> RenderPieSlice<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, string chartName, int uid, int id)
        where T : AuthTest.Models.HardDriveUsagePieSlice
    {return helper.Kendo().Chart<T>()
              .Theme("Uniform")
              .Name(chartName).Title(title => title.Position(ChartTitlePosition.Bottom))
              .Legend(legend => legend
                  .Visible(false)
              )
              .Series(series =>
              {
                  series.Pie(model => model.Percent, model => model.Title)

                      .Labels(labels => labels
                          .Template("#= category #: #= value#%")
                          .Background("transparent")
                          .Visible(true)
                      ).StartAngle(150);
              })
              .DataSource(x => x.Read(r => r.Action("_Usage", "Home", new {ID = id, UID = uid})))
              .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                    .Visible(true)
                    .Format("{0}%")
              ).Transitions(false);
}
```

Then in your cshtml file, you can call it like so:

```
 @(Html.RenderPieSlice<AuthTest.Models.HardDriveUsagePieSlice>("MyPieSliceName",s.Value.Id, Model.UID))
```

I havent tested this exact code, but it should be (somewhat) correct. I hope this helps. Good luck!